# MYSQL, How to compare ID with other column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in which I want to compare an ID column with another column in the same table.
This is my table

```
ID | Name | BossID
1    John     3
2    Max      4
3    Peter    4
4    Alex     5
```

For example I want to use

```
select * from mytable where ID = BossID
```

and I expected to get that Peter is the Boss of John and Alex is the Boss of Max and Peter, but when I use it this way, I dont get any info on the query...

Any idea to get it?

The expected query result are:

```
ID | Name | BossID
1    John     3
2    Max      4
3    Peter    4
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

seems like you want the list of employees who their boss exists in the list as well:

```
select *
from mytable
where bossid in (select id from mytable);
```

to get the boss name :

```
select t.ID, t.Name, b.Name as BossName  
from mytable t
join mytbale b
 on t.bossid = b.id
```

you can use `left join` to return all the employees in the list

Comment: you ara awesome! Now I have another question! How Can I replace the BossID with the name of the Boss, something like:  

select IF(bossid = id, Name, Other)
from mytable
where bossid in (select id from mytable);